# gtag.js transfers custom_map and ecommerce variables as [Object object]

Tags: google-analytics

I have been struggling to set up analytics with custom dimensions and ecommerce and I've been having a hard time finding answers so far. I have previously created an issue on stackoverflow as well as on analytics help community and was told my description was confusing. So here I am trying to provide a better and more hands-on description of my issue in hopes someone would see what am I doing wrong.

To start with, these are the guides I have been following:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/custom-dims-mets
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/ecommerce

The problem is that both `custom_dimensions` and `items` in the purchase event are transferred as `[Object object]` to the dashboard. Here is a step by step representation of what I am doing:

### The setup

[image]

### The data layer

[image]

### The collect request

[image]

### The firebase dashboard

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably using App+Web property tracking ID that doesn't support standard ecommerce tracking and reporting. The guides you're referencing to are for standard Google Analytics properties.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to apply App + Web Property on my website&app, and i have same issue with the problem.

Below Google support suggests 'array' format to send 'items' (in add_to_cart event) data.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/app-web/tag-guide

but app+web property dashboard shows just [object Object]...